# How can you mathematically prove that a mergesort that divides each list into more than two sublists is a less efficient value in O(nlogn)?

Tags: big-o, mergesort

I know that a mergesort that divides a list into 3 or more sublists instead of 2 is still O(nlogn) and is less efficient that a 2 sublist mergesort (because it has to do more comparisons in merge), but I need to mathematically prove it. I'm assuming some form of induction would do it, but I'm having trouble thinking about how to approach the problem.

Any approaches?

Comment: Well they're more comparisons, but still a constant number (3), which doesn't vary with the length of the list (`n`), so I'm not sure if the time complexity would actually change

Comment: By less efficient I mean it's the same Big-O but has a constant coefficient that makes its runtime greater. From my understanding, that is true since the comparisons in merge take more time than changing the base of the log on the mergesort, but again, I don't know how to mathematically prove that.

Comment: Yeah, I think the multiplicative coefficient would be different. I would start this by first looking at some existing proofs about regular divide-by-two merge sort, and see how to generalize from there